# Two columns into one on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in one table. I have created a third column in that same table and I want to concatenates both columns into the third. For example, I have two columns, first_name and last_name. The third column is titled full_name. What would I write as a sql query to combine first_name and last_name to combine and insert into full_name. Also, I want to concatenate a space between both columns when being inserted into full_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CONCAT()`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    full_name = CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
```

If either first_name or last_name can contain `NULL` values, you'll want to do:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    full_name = CONCAT(IFNULL(first_name, ''), ' ', IFNULL(last_name, ''))
```

So as to prevent a `NULL` value being returned when just one of the parameters to `CONCAT` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle:

```
update your_table
   set full_name = first_name || ' ' || last_name
```

Comment: I'm not using Oracle. I'm using the whole PHP mysql ordeal. Unless I completely missed something.